# I'd be grateful if somebody could help me with this probability problem.

Tags: probability

The gross weekly sales at a certain restaurant are a normal random variable with mean \$2200 and standard deviation \$230. What is the probability that

a. the total gross sales over the next 2 weeks exceeds \$5000

b. weekly sales exceed \$2200 in at least 2 of the next 3 weeks?

Don't just give me the answer. I need to know how to get there. Thanks in advance!

Comment: If you change your title to reflect the content of the problem, you will probably get more responses

Comment: What work have you done so far on this question?